# Localizations of hereditary rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

It is known that if a commutative Noetherian ring  $R$ is hereditary then for any maximal ideal $M$ the localization $R_M$ is also hereditary. Is the Noetherian assumption necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to suppose your ring to be noetherian. In fact, the following stronger statement is true:

> If $R$ is a hereditary commutative ring and $S\subseteq R$ is a subset, then the ring $S^{-1}R$ is hereditary.

In order to prove this we use the following two facts:

1) A commutative ring $R$ is hereditary if and only if any epimorphism of $R$-modules with injective source has injective target (i.e., quotients of injectives are injective). (See e.g. T.Y. Lam, *Lectures on modules and rings,* Theorem 3.22.)

2) If $R$ is a commutative ring, $S\subseteq R$ is a subset an $M$ is an $S^{-1}R$-module, then $M$ is injective if and only if it is so considered as an $R$-module by means of scalar restriction. (See e.g. M.P. Brodmann, R.Y. Sharp, *Local cohomology,* Lemma 10.1.12 (where the noetherian hypothesis is not used), or E.C. Dade, *Localization of injective modules,* J. Algebra 69 (1981), 416--425.)

Now, suppose that $R$ is a hereditary commutative ring and consider a subset $S\subseteq R$. Let $M\rightarrow N$ be an epimorphism of $S^{-1}R$-modules with injective source. By means of scalar restriction to $R$ we can consider this as an epimorphism $M\rightarrow N$ of $R$-modules with injective source by 2). Hence, its target is injective by 1), and therefore the $S^{-1}R$-module $N$ is injective by 2). It follows that $S^{-1}R$ is hereditary.

Comment: Is commutativity of $R$ necessary or is it sufficient to suppose that $S$ satisfies the Ore conditions ?

Comment: @tj_: Statement 1) is proven in the non-commutative case in Lam's book. I _think_ statement 2) also generalises (and hence so does the whole thing), but since I usually do not work with non-commutative rings it might be safer for you to check this again.

Comment: Can't you proceed directly? Assume $M$ is a submodule of a free $S^{-1}R$-module $F$. Then $F=S^{-1}F_0$ with $F_0$ $R$-free with same basis. Let $j:F_0\to F$ be the canonical map. Put $M_0=j^{-1}(M)$. Then $M=S^{-1}M_0$ (easy) and $M_0$ is $R$-projective by assumption on $R$, so $M$ is $S^{-1}R$-projective. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Laurent: Your proof is definitely the easier one. (I just happen to like injectives so much...)